# R - Efficiently reshape time series variable columns into time series rows with columns as variables

Tags: r, time-series, reshape

I suppose this need not be strictly time series data, but I couldn't see how else to frame the question...

I have a data table with rows as unique XY locations and columns of ID, X, and Y, and then 12 monthly columns for several climate variables:

- Mean temperature (Tmean) for months 1-12, named Tmean01, Tmean02 ... Tmean12.
- Max temperature (Tmax) for months 1-12, named Tmax01, Tmaxe02 ... Tmax12.
- Min temperature (Tmax) for months 1-12, named Tmax01, Tmaxe02 ... Tmax12.

The data look like this:

```
  ID   lat   long Tave01 Tave02 Tave03 Tave04 Tave05 Tave06 Tave07 Tave08 Tave09 Tave10 Tave11 Tave12 Tmax01 Tmax02 Tmax03 Tmax04 Tmax05 Tmax06 Tmax07 Tmax08 Tmax09 Tmax10 Tmax11 Tmax12 Tmin01 Tmin02 Tmin03 Tmin04 Tmin05 Tmin06 Tmin07 Tmin08 Tmin09 Tmin10 Tmin11 Tmin12
F102  51.5 -116.3  -12.8   -9.2   -4.6   -0.9    4.1    5.8    9.5    8.1    3.2   -1.1   -7.4  -12.0   -8.0   -2.8    0.4    5.2   10.5    9.9   15.0   14.3    8.1    2.5   -4.8   -7.6  -17.5  -15.6   -9.5   -6.9   -2.2    1.7    3.9    1.9   -1.7   -4.7  -10.0  -16.4
F103  51.5 -116.2  -13.0   -9.5   -4.9   -1.2    4.0    5.7    9.4    8.0    3.1   -1.1   -7.6  -12.3   -7.9   -2.9    0.2    5.0   10.3    9.8   15.0   14.3    8.1    2.7   -4.6   -7.6  -18.1  -16.1  -10.0   -7.3   -2.4    1.7    3.7    1.7   -1.9   -5.0  -10.6  -17.0
F105  51.5 -116.1  -13.7  -10.8   -6.5   -3.5    1.8    4.2    7.6    6.1    1.5   -2.7   -9.1  -13.5   -8.7   -4.7   -1.8    2.2    7.6    7.1   12.2   11.5    5.7    1.1   -6.9   -9.1  -18.8  -17.0  -11.2   -9.2   -3.9    1.2    2.9    0.7   -2.7   -6.5  -11.3  -18.0
F106  51.5 -116.0  -13.7  -10.8   -6.4   -3.3    1.8    4.2    7.7    6.2    1.7   -2.5   -9.0  -13.4   -8.5   -4.7   -1.9    2.6    7.8    7.3   12.5   11.9    6.0    1.7   -6.8   -8.9  -18.8  -16.9  -11.0   -9.3   -4.3    1.1    2.9    0.6   -2.7   -6.6  -11.2  -17.9
F116  51.5 -115.3  -11.3   -7.8   -2.8    1.2    5.9    7.6   11.6   10.1    5.4    2.4   -3.9  -10.2   -5.7   -0.7    2.4    8.4   13.4   12.7   18.3   17.3   11.4    9.0    0.8   -5.1  -17.0  -15.0   -8.1   -5.9   -1.5    2.4    4.9    2.9   -0.7   -4.2   -8.7  -15.3
F117  51.5 -115.2  -11.2   -7.7   -2.6    1.4    6.2    7.8   11.8   10.3    5.6    2.6   -3.7  -10.1   -5.6   -0.5    2.8    8.6   13.6   13.0   18.6   17.5   11.7    9.2    1.2   -4.9  -16.9  -14.9   -8.0   -5.8   -1.3    2.6    5.0    3.1   -0.5   -4.1   -8.6  -15.2
F118  51.5 -115.1  -11.1   -7.4   -2.4    1.6    6.4    8.1   12.0   10.6    5.9    2.7   -3.4   -9.9   -5.4   -0.1    3.2    8.9   13.9   13.3   18.9   17.7   11.9    9.4    1.8   -4.7  -16.8  -14.7   -8.0   -5.6   -1.0    2.8    5.2    3.6   -0.1   -3.9   -8.6  -15.0
F119  51.5 -115.0  -10.9   -7.2   -2.2    1.9    6.7    8.4   12.3   10.9    6.2    3.0   -2.9   -9.6   -5.2    0.3    3.6    9.3   14.2   13.7   19.3   18.1   12.3    9.7    2.6   -4.3  -16.7  -14.6   -8.0   -5.4   -0.8    3.0    5.4    3.8    0.1   -3.8   -8.4  -14.8
F120  51.5 -114.9  -10.6   -6.6   -1.7    2.4    7.0    8.6   12.6   11.0    6.3    3.3   -2.5   -9.0   -4.7    1.1    4.4    9.8   14.7   14.2   19.8   18.5   12.9   10.1    3.1   -3.4  -16.5  -14.3   -7.9   -5.0   -0.8    3.1    5.3    3.4   -0.2   -3.5   -8.2  -14.5
F121  51.5 -114.8  -10.3   -6.2   -1.3    2.7    7.2    8.9   12.7   11.2    6.5    3.5   -2.3   -8.5   -4.2    1.7    5.1   10.2   15.1   14.7   20.3   18.9   13.3   10.4    3.3   -2.8  -16.3  -14.0   -7.7   -4.7   -0.7    3.1    5.2    3.4   -0.4   -3.4   -7.8  -14.2
...
```

What I would like to have is a time-series layout, where each row represents a monthly entry for each discrete ID with the variables (Tmean, Tmin, Tmax) as columns. So I would end up with 12 rows for each unique ID. Something like this...

```
  ID Month  Tave Tmax  Tmin
F102     1 -12.8 -8.0 -17.5
F102     2  -9.2 -2.8 -15.6
F102     3  -4.6  0.4  -9.5
F102     4   4.1  5.2  -6.9
...
F102    12 -12.0 -7.6 -16.4
F103     1 -13.0 -7.9 -17.5
F103     2  -9.5 -2.9 -16.1
...
```

And so forth for each station and each month.

I can brute force this with a loop or something through all variables and populate an *expand.grid* table or something, but there must be a more elegant (i.e. faster and easier) solution.

I've looked through the *reshape* package, but can't seem to track down what I need.

Comment: Thanks Henrik. The "wide format" to "long format" was the vocabulary that I was missing in my searches. This answer using *reshape* is exactly what I need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085161/reshape-a-dataframe-with-tidyr-or-reshape2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. We can use `gather` to convert the data frame to long format. Use `separate` to separate the column to `Measure` and `Month`. Notice that the `sep` argument can specify which postion to separate the column. `convert` can determine if we want to convert columns to numeric if possible. Finally, use spread to convert it to the desired output (`dt2`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  select(-lat, -long) %>%
  gather(Type, Value, -ID) %>%
  separate(Type, into = c("Measure", "Month"), sep = 4, convert = TRUE) %>%
  spread(Measure, Value)
```

Data:

```
dt <- read.table(text = "ID   lat   long Tave01 Tave02 Tave03 Tave04 Tave05 Tave06 Tave07 Tave08 Tave09 Tave10 Tave11 Tave12 Tmax01 Tmax02 Tmax03 Tmax04 Tmax05 Tmax06 Tmax07 Tmax08 Tmax09 Tmax10 Tmax11 Tmax12 Tmin01 Tmin02 Tmin03 Tmin04 Tmin05 Tmin06 Tmin07 Tmin08 Tmin09 Tmin10 Tmin11 Tmin12
F102  51.5 -116.3  -12.8   -9.2   -4.6   -0.9    4.1    5.8    9.5    8.1    3.2   -1.1   -7.4  -12.0   -8.0   -2.8    0.4    5.2   10.5    9.9   15.0   14.3    8.1    2.5   -4.8   -7.6  -17.5  -15.6   -9.5   -6.9   -2.2    1.7    3.9    1.9   -1.7   -4.7  -10.0  -16.4
                 F103  51.5 -116.2  -13.0   -9.5   -4.9   -1.2    4.0    5.7    9.4    8.0    3.1   -1.1   -7.6  -12.3   -7.9   -2.9    0.2    5.0   10.3    9.8   15.0   14.3    8.1    2.7   -4.6   -7.6  -18.1  -16.1  -10.0   -7.3   -2.4    1.7    3.7    1.7   -1.9   -5.0  -10.6  -17.0
                 F105  51.5 -116.1  -13.7  -10.8   -6.5   -3.5    1.8    4.2    7.6    6.1    1.5   -2.7   -9.1  -13.5   -8.7   -4.7   -1.8    2.2    7.6    7.1   12.2   11.5    5.7    1.1   -6.9   -9.1  -18.8  -17.0  -11.2   -9.2   -3.9    1.2    2.9    0.7   -2.7   -6.5  -11.3  -18.0
                 F106  51.5 -116.0  -13.7  -10.8   -6.4   -3.3    1.8    4.2    7.7    6.2    1.7   -2.5   -9.0  -13.4   -8.5   -4.7   -1.9    2.6    7.8    7.3   12.5   11.9    6.0    1.7   -6.8   -8.9  -18.8  -16.9  -11.0   -9.3   -4.3    1.1    2.9    0.6   -2.7   -6.6  -11.2  -17.9
                 F116  51.5 -115.3  -11.3   -7.8   -2.8    1.2    5.9    7.6   11.6   10.1    5.4    2.4   -3.9  -10.2   -5.7   -0.7    2.4    8.4   13.4   12.7   18.3   17.3   11.4    9.0    0.8   -5.1  -17.0  -15.0   -8.1   -5.9   -1.5    2.4    4.9    2.9   -0.7   -4.2   -8.7  -15.3
                 F117  51.5 -115.2  -11.2   -7.7   -2.6    1.4    6.2    7.8   11.8   10.3    5.6    2.6   -3.7  -10.1   -5.6   -0.5    2.8    8.6   13.6   13.0   18.6   17.5   11.7    9.2    1.2   -4.9  -16.9  -14.9   -8.0   -5.8   -1.3    2.6    5.0    3.1   -0.5   -4.1   -8.6  -15.2
                 F118  51.5 -115.1  -11.1   -7.4   -2.4    1.6    6.4    8.1   12.0   10.6    5.9    2.7   -3.4   -9.9   -5.4   -0.1    3.2    8.9   13.9   13.3   18.9   17.7   11.9    9.4    1.8   -4.7  -16.8  -14.7   -8.0   -5.6   -1.0    2.8    5.2    3.6   -0.1   -3.9   -8.6  -15.0
                 F119  51.5 -115.0  -10.9   -7.2   -2.2    1.9    6.7    8.4   12.3   10.9    6.2    3.0   -2.9   -9.6   -5.2    0.3    3.6    9.3   14.2   13.7   19.3   18.1   12.3    9.7    2.6   -4.3  -16.7  -14.6   -8.0   -5.4   -0.8    3.0    5.4    3.8    0.1   -3.8   -8.4  -14.8
                 F120  51.5 -114.9  -10.6   -6.6   -1.7    2.4    7.0    8.6   12.6   11.0    6.3    3.3   -2.5   -9.0   -4.7    1.1    4.4    9.8   14.7   14.2   19.8   18.5   12.9   10.1    3.1   -3.4  -16.5  -14.3   -7.9   -5.0   -0.8    3.1    5.3    3.4   -0.2   -3.5   -8.2  -14.5
                 F121  51.5 -114.8  -10.3   -6.2   -1.3    2.7    7.2    8.9   12.7   11.2    6.5    3.5   -2.3   -8.5   -4.2    1.7    5.1   10.2   15.1   14.7   20.3   18.9   13.3   10.4    3.3   -2.8  -16.3  -14.0   -7.7   -4.7   -0.7    3.1    5.2    3.4   -0.4   -3.4   -7.8  -14.2",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` solution. Definitely not the cleanest solution. I just liked the challenge of the problem... and just played around until I got it right:

```
# Set to data.table
setDT(df)

# Melt to long form
dfl <- melt(df, id.vars = c("ID", "lat","long"))
dfl
       ID  lat   long variable value
  1: F102 51.5 -116.3   Tave01 -12.8
  2: F103 51.5 -116.2   Tave01 -13.0
  3: F105 51.5 -116.1   Tave01 -13.7
  4: F106 51.5 -116.0   Tave01 -13.7
  5: F116 51.5 -115.3   Tave01 -11.3
 ---                                
356: F117 51.5 -115.2   Tmin12 -15.2
357: F118 51.5 -115.1   Tmin12 -15.0
358: F119 51.5 -115.0   Tmin12 -14.8
359: F120 51.5 -114.9   Tmin12 -14.5
360: F121 51.5 -114.8   Tmin12 -14.2

# Add new variables, month and variable type using regex
dfl[, Month := gsub(".+([0-9]{2})$", "\\1", variable)]
dfl[, var_type := gsub("(.{4}).+$", "\\1", variable)]

# Take to final form
dfw <- reshape(dfl, idvar = c("ID", "lat","long", "Month"), timevar = "var_type", direction = "wide")

# Get rid of extra columns that are not needed anymore
dfw[, grep("variable\\.", names(dfw), value = TRUE) := NULL]
dfw[, c("lat", "long") := NULL]

# Cleaning the names a bit
names(dfw) <- gsub("value\\.", "", names(dfw)) 

# Print final product
dfw
       ID Month  Tave Tmax  Tmin
  1: F102    01 -12.8 -8.0 -17.5
  2: F103    01 -13.0 -7.9 -18.1
  3: F105    01 -13.7 -8.7 -18.8
  4: F106    01 -13.7 -8.5 -18.8
  5: F116    01 -11.3 -5.7 -17.0
 ---                            
116: F117    12 -10.1 -4.9 -15.2
117: F118    12  -9.9 -4.7 -15.0
118: F119    12  -9.6 -4.3 -14.8
119: F120    12  -9.0 -3.4 -14.5
120: F121    12  -8.5 -2.8 -14.2
```

**EDIT**

Based on the link provided in comments, I came up with another shorter version that does the job:

```
dfw <- reshape(df, idvar="ID", direction="long", 
               varying=list(ave=4:15, max=16:27, min=28:39),
               v.names = c("Tave", "Tmax", "Tmin"))
setnames(dfw, "time", "Month")
dfw[, c("lat", "long") := NULL]
```

Comment: Thanks snoram: works as you describe. It's about where I started on all this. I marked is as an answer, though the solution using *reshape* that Henrik linked to above cuts the coding to a minimum!

Comment: It is definitely *faster and easier* than a loop, but I'm glad there exists a shorter solution, I will take a look at the link.

Comment: Updated with a **much** shorter version based on the link. I doubt there exists a much faster and shorter version in R.

Answer (score 1):

To add something useful to the *reshape* solution (to make up for asking a duplicate question), I'll include here a quick *for* loop script to make the the *varying* list in the reshape command (which is useful with large datasets).

You can start by using ycw's *read.table* line to build the data (which I won't repeat here).

```
foo <- read.table...

# Make a list of the variable names (minus month or time numbers)
foo.vars <- c("Tave","Tmax","Tmin")

# Loop to make a list of variable column numbers
for(i in 1:length(foo.vars)){
  if(i==1) reshape.list <- list()
  reshape.list[[i]] <- grep(foo.vars[i],names(foo))
}
```

This creates the list of column numbers for each variable, to be identified in the *varying* option of the reshape command:

```
reshape.list
[[1]]
 [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15

[[2]]
 [1] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27

[[3]]
 [1] 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
```

Then the actual reshape command:

```
# Reshape command to make a ling table from the wide table
foo.long <- reshape(foo, idvar="ID", direction="long", varying=reshape.list, timevar="Month", v.names=foo.vars)
foo.long <- foo.long[order(foo.long$ID,foo.long$Month),]
```

The code returns the data as desired:

```
  ID  lat   long Month  Tave Tmax  Tmin
F102 51.5 -116.3     1 -12.8 -8.0 -17.5
F102 51.5 -116.3     2  -9.2 -2.8 -15.6
F102 51.5 -116.3     3  -4.6  0.4  -9.5
F102 51.5 -116.3     4  -0.9  5.2  -6.9
F102 51.5 -116.3     5   4.1 10.5  -2.2
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidyverse solution, which I think you can scale. This solution is when you can't use `separate` function:

## data

```
df1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
      ID = c("F102", "F103", "F105", "F106", "F116", "F117", "F118",
             "F119", "F120", "F121"),
     lat = c(51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5),
    long = c(-116.3, -116.2, -116.1, -116, -115.3, -115.2, -115.1, -115,
             -114.9, -114.8),
  Tave01 = c(-12.8, -13, -13.7, -13.7, -11.3, -11.2, -11.1, -10.9, -10.6,
             -10.3),
  Tave02 = c(-9.2, -9.5, -10.8, -10.8, -7.8, -7.7, -7.4, -7.2, -6.6, -6.2),
  Tave03 = c(-4.6, -4.9, -6.5, -6.4, -2.8, -2.6, -2.4, -2.2, -1.7, -1.3),
  Tave04 = c(-0.9, -1.2, -3.5, -3.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.9, 2.4, 2.7),
  Tave05 = c(4.1, 4, 1.8, 1.8, 5.9, 6.2, 6.4, 6.7, 7, 7.2),
  Tave06 = c(5.8, 5.7, 4.2, 4.2, 7.6, 7.8, 8.1, 8.4, 8.6, 8.9),
  Tave07 = c(9.5, 9.4, 7.6, 7.7, 11.6, 11.8, 12, 12.3, 12.6, 12.7),
  Tave08 = c(8.1, 8, 6.1, 6.2, 10.1, 10.3, 10.6, 10.9, 11, 11.2),
  Tave09 = c(3.2, 3.1, 1.5, 1.7, 5.4, 5.6, 5.9, 6.2, 6.3, 6.5),
  Tave10 = c(-1.1, -1.1, -2.7, -2.5, 2.4, 2.6, 2.7, 3, 3.3, 3.5),
  Tave11 = c(-7.4, -7.6, -9.1, -9, -3.9, -3.7, -3.4, -2.9, -2.5, -2.3),
  Tave12 = c(-12, -12.3, -13.5, -13.4, -10.2, -10.1, -9.9, -9.6, -9, -8.5),
  Tmax01 = c(-8, -7.9, -8.7, -8.5, -5.7, -5.6, -5.4, -5.2, -4.7, -4.2),
  Tmax02 = c(-2.8, -2.9, -4.7, -4.7, -0.7, -0.5, -0.1, 0.3, 1.1, 1.7),
  Tmax03 = c(0.4, 0.2, -1.8, -1.9, 2.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3.6, 4.4, 5.1),
  Tmax04 = c(5.2, 5, 2.2, 2.6, 8.4, 8.6, 8.9, 9.3, 9.8, 10.2),
  Tmax05 = c(10.5, 10.3, 7.6, 7.8, 13.4, 13.6, 13.9, 14.2, 14.7, 15.1),
  Tmax06 = c(9.9, 9.8, 7.1, 7.3, 12.7, 13, 13.3, 13.7, 14.2, 14.7),
  Tmax07 = c(15, 15, 12.2, 12.5, 18.3, 18.6, 18.9, 19.3, 19.8, 20.3),
  Tmax08 = c(14.3, 14.3, 11.5, 11.9, 17.3, 17.5, 17.7, 18.1, 18.5, 18.9),
  Tmax09 = c(8.1, 8.1, 5.7, 6, 11.4, 11.7, 11.9, 12.3, 12.9, 13.3),
  Tmax10 = c(2.5, 2.7, 1.1, 1.7, 9, 9.2, 9.4, 9.7, 10.1, 10.4),
  Tmax11 = c(-4.8, -4.6, -6.9, -6.8, 0.8, 1.2, 1.8, 2.6, 3.1, 3.3),
  Tmax12 = c(-7.6, -7.6, -9.1, -8.9, -5.1, -4.9, -4.7, -4.3, -3.4, -2.8),
  Tmin01 = c(-17.5, -18.1, -18.8, -18.8, -17, -16.9, -16.8, -16.7, -16.5,
             -16.3),
  Tmin02 = c(-15.6, -16.1, -17, -16.9, -15, -14.9, -14.7, -14.6, -14.3, -14),
  Tmin03 = c(-9.5, -10, -11.2, -11, -8.1, -8, -8, -8, -7.9, -7.7),
  Tmin04 = c(-6.9, -7.3, -9.2, -9.3, -5.9, -5.8, -5.6, -5.4, -5, -4.7),
  Tmin05 = c(-2.2, -2.4, -3.9, -4.3, -1.5, -1.3, -1, -0.8, -0.8, -0.7),
  Tmin06 = c(1.7, 1.7, 1.2, 1.1, 2.4, 2.6, 2.8, 3, 3.1, 3.1),
  Tmin07 = c(3.9, 3.7, 2.9, 2.9, 4.9, 5, 5.2, 5.4, 5.3, 5.2),
  Tmin08 = c(1.9, 1.7, 0.7, 0.6, 2.9, 3.1, 3.6, 3.8, 3.4, 3.4),
  Tmin09 = c(-1.7, -1.9, -2.7, -2.7, -0.7, -0.5, -0.1, 0.1, -0.2, -0.4),
  Tmin10 = c(-4.7, -5, -6.5, -6.6, -4.2, -4.1, -3.9, -3.8, -3.5, -3.4),
  Tmin11 = c(-10, -10.6, -11.3, -11.2, -8.7, -8.6, -8.6, -8.4, -8.2, -7.8),
  Tmin12 = c(-16.4, -17, -18, -17.9, -15.3, -15.2, -15, -14.8, -14.5, -14.2)
```

)

## Library, function to extract alpha and Code

```html
library(tidyr)
library(readr)

extract.alpha <- function(x, space = ""){      
        require(stringr)
        require(purrr)
        require(magrittr)
        
        y <- strsplit(unlist(x), "[^a-zA-Z]+") 
        z <- y %>% map(~paste(., collapse = space)) %>% simplify()
        return(z)}

df1 %>%
        gather(Variable, Value, -c(ID, lat, long)) %>%
        mutate(Month = parse_number(Variable),
               Variable2 = extract.alpha(Variable)) %>% 
        select(-c(Variable, lat, long)) %>%
        spread(Variable2, Value)
```